# Ui overlapping using high charts in ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic-native

Ui is overlap using high carts in ionic angular for mobile
[This is first image and it's shown overlap in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPTbQ.jpg)

[This is second image in this image I clicked 2023 option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKqBN.jpg)

[This is third image in this image I clicked 2023 option again then it showing correctly without overlap so I want like this image without clicking 2023 option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2wLP.jpg)

I tryed in ionic angular in mobile and tab

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? - Read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if i used directly or inside the  tag highcharts is not overlap but if i used inside the ion-card tag then high chart will overlap for first time

issues is from ion-content tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).